# Convert .key formatted private key into .pem format with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, cryptography, private-key

I am trying to convert .key formatted private key into .pem formatted key using python3. Before using python3 I was able to convert private key into .pem format by simply running openssl command as:

```
openssl rsa -in <private_key_file> -outform PEM -out <new_file>
```

I would like to know how people are using python3 to convert it private keys into .pem or other formats. So far I've tried running `subprocess.run()` command to execute openssl command from python. It would be nice to know if there is python way of converting into .pem format.

I also tried following using pycryptodrome library https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html as per this thread [pyOpenSSL creating a pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651587/pyopenssl-creating-a-pem-file) which creates in pem format but wasn't successful.

```
 def convert_key_to_pem_format(key_file):
     print("Converting to pem/rsa format")
     pv_key_string = key_file.exportKey()
     with open ("private.pem", "w") as prv_file:
     print("{}".format(pv_key_string.decode()), file=prv_file)
```

This is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by _.key_ formatted. Possibly PKCS#8, since the posted statement can convert a PKCS#8 to a PKCS#1 key (PEM encoded). Please post an example of your keys (or the respective headers in case of PEM encoding).

Comment: It's a mistake to assume that the file extension uniquely identifies the format of cryptographic keys. Unfortunately, neither `.pem` nor `.key` does so. When I create files for my crypto experiments I always try to use a unique suffix, like `.pk8` for PKCS#8 private keys.

Answer (score 0):

From the Cryptodome library, you can use the `import_key` method, which supports the following formats for an RSA *private key*:

- PKCS#1 `RSAPrivateKey` DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
- PKCS#8_ `PrivateKeyInfo` or `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)

Here's how you could use it:

```
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.import_key(open('private.key', "rb").read(), passphrase="(passphrase in case you have one)")

pv_key_string = key.exportKey()
with open ("private.pem", "w") as prv_file:
    print("{}".format(pv_key_string.decode()), file=prv_file)
```

Comment: According to the description of [`openssl rsa`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-rsa.html) `PEM` is the default regarding `-inform` / `-outform`.

Comment: @Topaco, you're right, I've edited my answer accordingly.